C# DataGridView, automatic RowHeaders size calculation
I have a custom Gridview inherit from DataGrieviw, with an automatic RowHeadersWidthSizeMode set.
RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToDisplayedHeaders;
It seems that the final value of RowHeadersWidth is calculated not at contructor time, but only later, around the time the control is loaded.
In my application, the custom controls are all arranged next to each other depending on their size. It seems that I can't do this in the constructor, but only later, after the controls have been loaded.

This is the result when arrange the controls in the construcor.

Rearrangement after the load event gives the correct result.
Is there a way to force the calculation of the RowHeadersWidth programmatically in the construcor?
This is my CustomGrid:
    class CustomGridView : DataGridView
    {
        public CustomGridView()
        {
            RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToDisplayedHeaders;
            this.RowHeadersWidthChanged += CustomGridView_RowHeadersWidthChanged;
            ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
            InitGridView(3);
        }

        public void InitGridView(int numRows)
        {
            this.ColumnCount = 1;
            this.RowCount = numRows;
            for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
                Rows[row].HeaderCell.Value = "R" + (row+10).ToString();
                Rows[row].Cells[0] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            }

            Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            this.Height = this.RowCount * this.RowTemplate.Height + 4;
            this.Width = RowHeadersWidth + 45;
            // Unfortunately, RowHeadersWidth does not yet have the final value here at contructor time
        }

        private void CustomGridView_RowHeadersWidthChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // RowHeadersWidth is updated later, around the time the control is loaded
            this.Width = RowHeadersWidth + 45;
        }
    }

And this my main form:
     public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<CustomGridView> cGridViews = new List<CustomGridView>();
        private int gvWidth1;
        private int gvWidth2;

        private Point GridViewLocation;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GridViewLocation = new Point(10, 10);
            AddCustomGrid(new CustomGridView());
            AddCustomGrid(new CustomGridView());
            gvWidth1 = cGridViews[0].Width;
            this.Load += Form1_Load;
        }

        private void AddCustomGrid (CustomGridView cGridView)
        {
            cGridView.Location = GridViewLocation;
            this.Controls.Add(cGridView);
            cGridViews.Add(cGridView);
            GridViewLocation.X += cGridView.Width + 5;
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // CustomGridView now has the correct size
            gvWidth2 = cGridViews[0].Width;
        }
    }


DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill:

The column width adjusts so that the widths of all columns exactly
fills the display area of the control.

So if your RowHeadersWidth is changed by this, its value depends on your font, display DPI and many other display settings. It should be calculated before paint dynamically, and thus it can not be calculated in your grid constructor.

Setting this property has do not solve the problem.
